# Wordpress SMS API integration without plugin

Tags: api, sms

I am struggling with SMS sending in WordPress without plugin, I have a, API, but that API is not working.
Example:

```
function mysite_woocommerce_order_status_processing( $order_id ) {

    $mobile="123456";

    $url="****/api.php?username=******&password=1234&source=UPDATE&dmobile=".$mobile."&message='.$msg.' ";

    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );

    //print_r($response);

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing','mysite_woocommerce_order_status_processing' );
```

I am struggling with above hook, I can send Email through that hook, but not SMS. It would be great if any WordPress developer help me out !

Getting SyntaxError:

> JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: JSON.parse, as far I know, is a JavaScript method but you are showing us PHP code. Can you clarify where and where that syntax error appears?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the error. The last variable `$msg` is incorrectly inserted. Here is the corrected code.

```
function mysite_woocommerce_order_status_processing( $order_id ) {

    $mobile="123456";

    $url="****/api.php?username=******&password=1234&source=UPDATE&dmobile=".$mobile."&message='".$msg."'";

    $response = wp_remote_get( $url );

    //print_r($response);

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing','mysite_woocommerce_order_status_processing' );
```

Comment: i am sending SMS after woocommerce order is in processing, after place order

Answer (score -2):

```
function mysite_woocommerce_order_status_processing( $order_id ) {

  $mobile="123456";

  $url="****/api.php?username=******&password=1234&source=UPDATE&dmobile=".$mobile."&message='.$msg.' ";

  $response = file_get_contents( $url );

  //print_r($response);

   }

   add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_processing','mysite_woocommerce_order_status_processing' );
```

use `file_get_contents( $url )` instead of `wp_remote_get($url)` it will work fine

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/any-api-sms-for-woocommerce/ you can use any api , multiple options are there

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer, so anyone who reads the answer can understand what the code does.